# Understanding Ruby assignment syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, groovy

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to understand this syntax so I can convert to Groovy.
https://gist.github.com/brettporter/1723108

```
state = :body
```

and

```
conflict = {
            :lineno => index + 1
}
```

and

```
conflict[:left_conflict]
```

Are state and conflict objects with body and lineno and left_conflict fields??
And if so how is the left_conflict field populated/assigned a value?
Whats the equivalent way of doing this in Groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are `symbols` in Ruby.

```
state = :body
```

Sets the variable `state` to be the symbol `:body`

Groovy doesn't have symbols (see [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Do-we-have-ruby-s-symbols-analogue-td5715543.html)) so a possible Groovy replacement for these is to just use Strings as the state and map keys like:

```
// Just use a String to maintain our state
state = 'body'
```

and

```
// Create a map
conflict = [ lineno: index + 1 ]
```

and

```
// get a value from a map
conflict[ 'left_conflict' ]
```

It's probably wise to put these magic strings into some sort of final static variable

Answer (score 3):

[*Assignment*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment) :

> In Ruby assignment uses the = (equals sign) character. This example assigns the number five to the local variable v:
>
> v = 5
>
> Assignment creates a local variable if the variable was not previously referenced.

`state = :body` is called a local variable assignment with a [`Symbol`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Symbol.html) instance `:body`.

> Symbol objects represent names and some strings inside the Ruby interpreter. They are generated using the `:name` and `:"string"` literals syntax, and by the various `to_sym` methods

`conflict` is also a local variable, which is holding a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html) object.

`conflict[:left_conflict]`, here we are accessing a Hash's value with its key `:left_conflict` using a method [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).`:left_conflict` is a key of the hash object, which is being hold by `conflict` local variable.